# setting the system time with C#.NET without using kernel32.dll

Tags: .net, pinvoke, kernel32, systemtime

Is there a way to set the system time in C#.NET without using kernel32.dll?

I'm on a 64 bit system and calling the set time function seems to return "false" for me.

Comment: Your question is incorrect. It should be `When I try set the system time using p/invoke XXXX I get an error saying YYY, how do I correct the method call?` Asking for a workaround is the wrong approach.

Comment: you running elevated? that'd hsave to be in place.... - messing with the time is a privileged operation

Answer (score 1):

The .NET framework does not generally concern itself with low level system management concerns of this nature.

The problem here is that you cannot ask a question like this without telling us why it matters to you, so that people can properly contextualise an answer for you without having to be psychic.

Why do you need to do this? Will it be quicker? Are you worried the DLL might not be on the system :D

One way of finding out is to use Reflector (get it while it's hot) to look for the kernel32 method name- chances are whatever is wrapping it will be using P/Invoke and, unless they're paying silly buggers will just use the same name for the wrapper stub.

Comment: I don't like the name of the file kernel32.dll.  The file name looks strange because I am writing a 64 bit program.  I am looking for a workaround because you suggested the DLL might be missing.

Comment: @broiyan: I put a smiley on the suggestion that the file might be bissing for a reason. Syswow64 and friends and the, together that system32 doesnt always mean 'the 32 bit files live  here' are one of many reasons to not take 32 and 64 in a filename at face value. I suggest reading 32/64 articles on Raymond Chen's blog (thatoldnewthing.com) for good background ino.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Run as administrator or disable UAC -if any-